# how to create listview ui like this

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-studio

I create normal listview but  it not user friendly . I searching in google and find this pic of listview and i like create listview like this . 
i just need make boxing like this , shadow and like 3d !
[image]

this is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:divider="#a31405">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textDirection="rtl"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

my app is web based app and work with online database.
thank you.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the issue you are facing. This is  a simple listview with custom adapter and item.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 need make boxing like this , shadow and like 3d ! my listview is very very simple , just image and text and divider , no Effect like this .

Comment: You need to change the imageView image on selecting it . or you can keep two imageviews with either images and make on visible at a time

Comment: @user2003857 : For the boxing like this. Use cardview

Comment: its a recylerview with cardview..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CardView you can represent the information in a card manner with a drop shadow (`elevation`) and `corner radius` which looks consistent across the platform. `CardView` extends the FrameLayout and it is supported way back to Android 2.x.

You can achieve good looking UI when `CardView` is combined with `RecyclerView`.

Refer to this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cardview` and `RecylerView` for drop shadow `ListView`. See below link for sample projects:

[Sample1](http://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-android-cardview-example-tutorial) and [Sample2](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/11/android-recyclerview-example.html)